# aspect ratio for a game on different mobile device screens

Tags: android, ios, html, blackberry, image-resizing

i am making a game on different platforms, and i need to maintain a fixed aspect ratio while rescaling the game based on different device screen sizes...

1) so theres many different screen sizes because there are many different android, ios and blackberry devices. is there a suggested aspect ratio for all of them, a universal aspect ratio?

2) Otherwise, do each of these device have a different screen resolution (ie 540X480, 1024X720 etc)? Does that mean i have to target only a fixed number of mobile devices (ie 5), and mathematically find an aspect ratio for the screen resolution of each mobile device?

3) is there a more optimal way to do the above?

much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with game screen sizes, you usually want to have an fixed screen ratio (depending on the type of game), not to give some people an advantage and others a disadvantage (due to users playing your game on different devices).

I develop on a 320x470 ratio (since this is the most common screen ratio for Android mobile devices). I suggest you develop your game based on this ratio.

When actually rendering the framebuffer, you either stretch it to fill the screen or you use a technique called letterboxing. Both have their pros and cons.

I hope this gave you a greater insight and maybe an idea how you are going to tackle your problem.

Comment: thx for the advice, may i know how you came up with the 320X470 ratio?

Comment: This is a very common ratio for android devices.